# how to integrate Alfresco to my ios app?

Tags: ios, content-management-system, alfresco

In my ios app there are some information which I have to pull from some Content Management System(like Alfresco). Could You please suggest me, how can I integrate Alfresco to my ios app?

Comment: This is pretty open-ended for StackOverflow.  I suggest you narrow your question(s).  Asking "How do I create a CMS server" is pretty vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options available to you

One of them is to take the source code for [the Alfresco Mobile App for iOS](http://www.alfresco.com/products/mobile) which is open source, and start from there. Customise the Alfresco app to do all the additional things you need, with the Alfresco code as your starting point. This will work best if you basically want what the Alfresco App provides, with a few small changes.

The other is to use the CMIS library for iOS which the Alfresco mobile app uses, include that in your existing application, and interact with Alfresco via CMIS. It's also open source. See [cmis.alfresco.com](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) if you're new to CMIS and want to learn more.

You'll also likely want to join the [Alfresco Mobile Forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewforum.php?f=54&sid=4449ca39a6ee717b4d009780608c715b), which'll be the best place to get help with either the open source mobile app, or the iOS CMIS client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I downloaded 'ziadev-alfresco-mobile-24f591e113c5.zip' file of Alfresco Mobile app but not able to run it.This is the source code right?

Comment: I've no idea, where did you get it? The source repository [is on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/ziadev/alfresco-mobile/overview), you'll probably want to check the code out from there